# Sending E-Mail from contact form with the visitors sender address

Tags: php, email, gmail

I've built a contact form in which a sites visitor enters a message, subject and his own email address. The email then is sent to a fixed gmail address.

I'd like the receiver of the mail to be able to just click on answering in order to respond. Therefore I set the senders email to that one entered by the sites visitor.

Problem is, gmail considers those mails as spam. I guess because the DNS of the senders address does not fit to the servers IP.

So I wonder if there is a strategy to achieve what I have described.

Comment: If it is related to DNS settings, then PHP won't help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other email addresses you can add that will probably fix your problem. I suggest that you give your email From, Sender and Reply-To addresses:

```
From: visitor's email
Sender: your email
Reply-To: visitor's email
```

Reply-To is the address any reply will go to. Sender means that the email coming from you makes sense. From indicates that you are sending it on behalf of the visitor.

Comment: Didn't know about the Replay-To attribute :)